# Instagram photos urls (path) stable or not?

Tags: instagram

this is my first question ever

Ptohos on instagram have links like this:

[image]

Is it safe to use these photo urls (links) on my site to display those pictures, i mean whether they change frequently, if they change frequently its not safe for me to use those raw links do display pictures from instagram on my site because all galleries created with those let say "old" image path links wont work anymore...

I dont want download al those images and upload it on server btw...

Thanks for any help.
Regards,
and sry for my bad english

Comment: use instagram's api to get urls of images and throw them to html

Comment: Do you have any example, or can you give me some usefull links, maybe i could figure it out, i am not a programmer, i can do some litle php and javascript, but i need some help , thank you for your time and reply